# How do you draw the force in a clamped connection of 2 cilinders?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, forces, pressure

Something like this: 
[image]

There is pressure between the cilinders, and for some calculations we use the formula p=F/A, therefore F=p*A

If you were to draw the force F, where would you draw it? 
If the are was flat it would be like this: 
[image]

In the center of the surface. But for cilinder surface I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

In the second diagram the sum (resultant) of the forces on each element of the surface is the finite force $F$, represented by an arrow of finite length acting at the centre of the area. In the first diagram the resultant force is $F=0$, so it ought to be represented by an arrow of zero length - ie a point.

There is no conventional way of drawing the total compressive force on the red cylinder in the first diagram, other than the way you have already drawn it.